# UIScrollView addSubview of view that is already in the scrollview

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

I'm trying to find documentation regarding this occurrence but have struggled to find anything on this.

I have a scrollview and the subviews are (excuse the naming)

```
{
  aView,
  bView,
  cView,
  dView
}
```

if I add bView to the scrollView, like this

```
[myScrollview addSubview:bViewController.view];  //this being bView, same object
```

and then I output the subviews I get

```
{
  aView,
  cView
  dView,
  bView
}
```

Where bView is moved to the end. 
I was expecting

```
{
  aView,
  bView,
  cView
  dView,
  bView
}
```

Is this correct, can someone point me in the right direction (Apple docs)

Comment: seems like you need a new instance of `bView`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when adding images to my scroll view. The images would load, and then change at the last second. I figured out what to do by just copying and pasting around. You can try adding your image subviews right above everywhere the stream / scroll view data is loaded in the app, ideally viewdidload. How many times does your app call the data?